# git p4 how to submit a cl after a shelved cl is approved

Tags: git, version-control, perforce, git-p4

I currently have a project maintained in git.
Another team of the same project is using perforce.
And there's no way they're going to use git.

I'm trying to use git p4 to have both repositories updated using the guides in the following links.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4

https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/01/work-with-git-and-perforce/

https://owenou.com/git-up-perforce-with-git-p4

However, I'm getting stuck in Perforce's Swarm Review.

```
/home/user/projectgit << folder for git project where I work on
/home/user/projectp4 << workspace folder for git p4
```

Before submitting to Perforce, I must first shelve the updates which I can do by `git p4 submit --shelved`

Now after my cl is approved, how do I submit it?

There's no `git p4 submit <cl>`

I tried `git p4 unshelved <cl>`, but what do I do now with the unshelved commit in `refs/remote/p4/unsheved/<cl>`?

I also tried using `p4 submit <cl>` (while in the git p4's workspace) but it complains about no files to commit.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried using p4 submit  (while in the git p4's workspace) but it complains about no files to commit

You *can* do it by invoking p4 commands yourself, but since you ran into trouble (and probably aren't that interested in learning the p4 details) I suggest letting git-p4 do most of the work for you.

In your git repo, checkout the branch from which you did `git p4 submit --shelve` (or the commit that you created using `git p4 unshelve`), then just do `git p4 submit` (no `--shelve`).  It will create a new changelist from that same commit and submit it to perforce immediately.

You can also tidy up the perforce side by deleting the changelist that `git p4 submit --shelve` had created.  From the p4 workspace, run `p4 shelve -d <cl>` followed by `p4 change -d <cl>`.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want you can do the following:

```
p4 unshelve -s <shelf #> -c <shelf #>
p4 submit -c <shelf #>
p4 revert //...
```

Note: I do that from my git repo, but I have a valid .p4config file in that repo that points to the p4 workspace that I create my shelf in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `p4 edit`'ing those files? If not, try the following steps:

Step 1 of 4) `p4 edit` source code:

```
$: p4 edit <file1> <file2>
```

Step 2 of 4) `p4 edit -t text+x` scripts and/or binaries that need exec permission:

```
p4 edit -t text+x <script1>
```

Step 3 of 4) Check `p4 opened` to make sure all those files you want in the new changelist are listed:

```
$: p4 opened
```

Step 4 of 4) `p4 shelve` to get new changelist. If you want to submit to existing swarm review, you should add the existing swarm review number (#review-`<existing review number>`) to the commit description:

```
$: p4 shelve
```

Let's say the existing review number was 12345678, then you would want to add that to the description as shown below:

```
Description:
<tab>I want to add XYZ to this existing changelist #review-12345678 @<reviewer1> @<reviewer2>

<tab>This is a longer description explaining XYZ...
```